# How to enable autoscrolling for console logs using Safari inspector

Tags: safari, console.log, autoscroll, inspector

I can't seem to find an answer anywhere to this question.  The question has been asked before on this site and others, but no one ever answers it.  There should be an easy to find checkbox that enables/disables the autoscroll feature so the latest console log is shown, but I can't find it anywhere.  Not even chatGPT can solve my woes :(